# Mouse and keyboard input lag / stutter / jumping on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, mouse, 23.04

Working on a clean install of Ubuntu 23.04, fully updated. Most of the time, they keyboard and mouse are unusable: the mouse jumps / lags / stutters and the keyboard input takes a few ms to display on screen. I've been through a multitude of posts although none seem to help.

If it helps,

- the devices are connected over bluetooth.
- Models Logitech MX Mechanical & MX Master 3S.
- Interestingly, the mousepad on the laptop is silky smooth at all times.
- Switching to Xorg makes no difference.

The units are fine: I have two other machines (22.10 and 22.04 LTS) both work fine. Any suggestions?